# How to cancel progress bar of Main Activity when moving to a Fragment?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, progress-bar

I show a spinning progress bar before beginning a fragment. The run debugger shows that it is still running after the fragment is running and functioning.

Is there a proper way to end it? I simply want the user to know that something is happening while they wait (network connections, etc).

To expand a bit, the run monitoring of the emulator shows many lines like

```
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject
```

and these don't occur if I comment out the View.VISIBLE line of code

EDITED to note that those messages only appear in the run log if banner ads are enabled. I would assume that the bar is still spinning in either case, but just not flagged.

````
        binding.slowButton.setOnClickListener() {
            binding.pBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.mainActFields.visibility = View.GONE
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFragment,MainFragment()).commit()
            Log.i(MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, "Clicked")
        }



    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:progressTint="@color/white"
        android:foregroundTint="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:elevation="500dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `pBar` is an `Indeterminate Progress` , you're gonna need to call:

```
binding.pBar.visibility = View.GONE
```

to stop it.

What you need to do is delay close `pBar` (possibly using coroutines), but i think in this scenario using a `ProgressBar` when displaying your fragment is unnecessary unless `pBar` is from another fragment.

In the case of the log below,

```
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject
```

i think the `ad banner` is having a beef with `pBar` since it is visible and running indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, I haven't learned about co-routines yet. I was hoping tht there would just be something simple like:

doAfter(binding.pBar.visibility = View.GONE,3 secs)

Comment: In `coroutines` you can do something like [that](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines). If `MainFragment` does some long running operations, then you might want to move `pBar` inside `MainFragment`.

Comment: I finally learned a bit about co-routines and, yes, it is quite simple to build a delay function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can visibility gone of progress bar after fragment load.
add

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFragment,MainFragment()).commit()
binding.pBar.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: If I add the GONE command there then on my emulator the progress bar never shows. Edited to add thanks for looking in to it.